# Laravel FormRequest with Image Upload - Best Pratices

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, php-7

I often use FormRequest to avoid to leave validation rules on the Controller and usually I store the image and set it's path at the image field on the Controller.

It's the first time that I deal with these situations on same time, so my question is :

**Should I leave the upload in the Controller OR in the Form Request?**

Which one is the best pratice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormRequest should just be used for validation. Anything relating to processing/renaming/moving files etc should be within the controller. Although ideally it often makes sense for the Controller to pass this to a service which handles it, so you don't have business logic within the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, I'm asking that because I use the Fill method to insert all request incoming to the model object. In this specific cenario it won't work because I have to upload the file first to get it's path, so if I put the upload in the FormRequest I would pass to the controller a request with the file path on it...but it's not a best pratice...